# SQL query count (recursive)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following table on my database which contains some transactions for which I need to calc points and rewards.
Every time a `TxType A` occurs I should record 10 points.
Then I have to subtract from these points the value of the `PP` column every time a `TxType B` occurs.
When the calculation goes to zero a reward is reached.

```
ID  TxType  PP
1     A    0
2     B    2
3     B    1
4     B    1
5     B    1
6     B    3
7     B    1
8     B    1
9     A    0
10    B    4
11    B    3
12    B    2
13    B    1
14    A    0
15    B    2
```

I have created the sql query to calc points as follow

```
SELECT SUM(
   CASE 
      WHEN TxType = 'A' THEN 10
      WHEN TxType = 'B' THEN (PP * -1) 
   END)
FROM myTable
```

This query return the value of 8, which is exactly the number of points based on the sample data.
How do I calculate the rewards occurred (2 in the given example)?

thanks for helping

Comment: Can you clarify *"This query return the value of 8, which is exactly the number of points based on the sample data. How do I calculate the rewards occurred (2 in the given example)?"*  The query returns an entire data set. So its hard to tell what you're saying.

Comment: @Khan: sorry but my query just return a value, not an entire dataset. Did you missed the SUM function? The result 8 comes from 30 (value for each type A tx) less 22 (sum of PP when tx type B)

Comment: @Lorenzo Ah, yes I did.  But where does *2* come from?

Comment: @Khan: 2 are the rewards achieved. The customer get 1 reward everytime his card reach 0 points. TX id from 1 to 8 is the first reward, and from 9 to 13 the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff)'s the answer, you just need to count the records where `TheSum` is `0` to get how many rewards occurred:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM (
    SELECT  ID, 
            TxType, 
            PP,
            (   SELECT  SUM(CASE TxType WHEN 'A' THEN 10 WHEN 'B' THEN -PP END)
                FROM    #myTable t2
                WHERE   t2.id <= t1.id
            ) AS TheSum
    FROM #myTable t1
) Result
WHERE TheSum = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to do the calculation (in SQL Server 2008) using a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select sum(case when TxType = 'A' then 10
                        when TxType = 'B' then PP * -1
                   end)
        from mytable t2
        where t2.id <= t.id
       ) as TheSum
from mytable t;
```

You can then apply the logic of what happens when the value is 0.  In SQL Server 2012, you could just use a cumulative sum.

Comment: I think you're missing a `)` after `where t2.id <= t.id`

Comment: Yw.. +1, from what I can tell. This is what I'm expecting the OP is looking for.